# What type of electronic strike would work in 2" square tubing for a steel gate?

Tags: lock, mortise

I'm fabricating a 1.5" square steel tube gate mounted on 2" square steel tube posts.  The block wall is pre-wired for doorbell and electronic locking mechanism, but I just need to find the right strike mechanism that I can mortise into the 2" post.

I'm not exactly sure what the terminology is for what I'm looking for.  If anyone has any experience with this, I'd love to find the right hardware for an outdoor setup.

Comment: This, unfortunately, seems like it will devolve into a "shopping" question which is off-topic. It may help, though, if you were to at least indicate what types of products you've already looked at and why you've dismissed them as unsuitable, so that others could recommend a different product category that might work for you.